# Return a Collections.emptyList() fails with ternary operator

Tags: java, generics, collections, ternary-operator

I have a method to merge two Lists of the same type.

```
public <T> List<T> mergeList(List<T> first, List<T> second) {


    if(first != null && second != null && (first.addAll(second))){

        return first;
    } else {

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

There is no problem if use an if-else-block, but with the ternary operator:

```
public <T> List<T> mergeList(List<T> first, List<T> second) {

    return (first != null && second != null && first.addAll(second)) ? first : Collections.emptyList();

}
```

Eclipse says: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#1-of ? extends Object> to List<T>`

Why I can't return `Collections.emptyList()` here? I thought the ternary operator will be treated as if-else by the compiler?

Comment: Have you tried `Collections.<T>emptyList();`

Comment: Well the duplicate already answers it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
public <T> List<T> mergeList(List<T> first, List<T> second) {

  return (first != null && second != null && first.addAll(second)) 
    ? first 
    : Collections.<T>emptyList();

}
```

Note the use of `Collections.<T>emptyList()` instead of `Collections.emptyList()`.